# Can't connect Maria DB to AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to connect a Maria DB that is sitting in an EC2 to AWS Quicksight. This is the error I am getting  along with the specific error. [image: The host EC2 is not allowed to]

[image: Error when trying to connect QS to Maria DB[![][1]][1]]

What makes this confusing that I am able to connect to the Maria DB using a similar process with two separate database administration tools, i.e., Workbench and Sequel Pro. By similar process, I mean having to enter the host (for which I enter the host EC2's public DNS), username and password of Maria DB. I am able to connect from both tools with little issue. But when I try to connect using QuickSight, an AWS product, presumably the same network as EC2, I get the error message.

Some general troubleshooting steps I've taken

- Added EC2FullAccess to QuickSight IAM Role. (Although even after I
  added it in IAM, it is not shown in the Quicksight setting
  options[image: ![enter image description here][Ec2 Permission not

  showing in Quicksight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzJyU.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzJyU.png)

  - Made sure I was in the correct region, i.e., EC2 and Quicksight    aligned

    - Made sure port 3306 was open. Ran through firewalld and netstat drills.
    - Added port 3306 to security group
    - Added AWS-Quicksight-Access to security group and attached to EC2 (both to original security group and created separate security
      group    with just Quicksight rule and attached)

None of these steps have helped. I am now troubleshooting at VPC level but I stopped to asked for help for two reasons:

1. I didn't find anyone else who has run into this problem online/and solved it so I am wondering whether it is (my) account specific;
2. Supporting this theory is my Quicksight settings, which do not include my EC2 permission that I attached to the Quicksight role. I added it in my root account.

I hope this is enough. Thanks for your help.